# Fixed bottom div stop once it reaches another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fixed bottom div stop once it reaches another div

For ref- https://www.marketo.com/

```css
#one{
 width:100%;    
    background-color: aqua;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0px;
 padding: 30px 0;
 text-align: center;
}


#two{
 width: 100%;    
    padding: 30px 0;
 text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 900px; background: rgba(0,215,216,1.00)"></div>
     <div id="one" class="fixed">Main Flagasd</div>
  <div id="two">div 2</div>
  <div style="height: 900px; background: rgba(152,215,216,1.00)"></div>
```

Comment: No visible effort on your part, plus a duplicate of your own previous question, http://stackoverflow.com/q/43185460/1427878

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `scrollToFixed` jQuery plugin.  It will simplify your code drastically as well as produced the desired effect.  I drew up an example on how you can use it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#one').scrollToFixed( {
        bottom: 0,
        limit: $('#two').offset().top,
    });
});
```

```css
#one{
  background-color: aqua;
 padding: 30px 0;
 text-align: center;
}


#two{
 width: 100%;
  padding: 30px 0;
 text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bigspotteddog.github.io/ScrollToFixed/jquery-scrolltofixed-min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 900px; background: rgba(0,215,216,1.00)"></div>
     <div id="one" class="fixed">Main Flagasd</div>
  <div id="two">div 2</div>
  <div style="height: 900px; background: rgba(152,215,216,1.00)"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

*I am assuming that the `fixed div` will change its `position` when it reaches the `red div`.*

```js
var fixedDiv = document.querySelector('#one');
var redDiv = document.querySelector('#two');


redDiv.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {

  fixedDiv.style.position = 'static';

});
```

```css
#one {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: aqua;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  padding: 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#two {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 900px; background: rgba(0,215,216,1.00)"></div>
<div id="one" class="fixed">Main Flagasd</div>
<div id="two">div 2</div>
<div style="height: 900px; background: rgba(152,215,216,1.00)"></div>
```

Comment: Hi hunzaboy,
can you please check the reference link once.  
https://www.marketo.com/

Comment: if possible i need the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin called [ScrollToFixed](https://bigspotteddog.github.io/ScrollToFixed/)

as

```
$('.footer').scrollToFixed( {
        bottom: 0,
        limit: $('.footer').offset().top,

    });
```

working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZczEt/2953/

Comment: If you are looking for a solution without any extra plugin then can do custom as https://jsfiddle.net/livibetter/HV9HM/ this example is for top bar bix but you can get an understanding of the implementation